# Create album with friends access

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

im using $create_album = $facebook->api("/{$user_profile['id']}/albums", 'post', $album_details); to create a album, and the album sharing is set to public, how i create a album with friends share?

Answer (score 1):

In most calls to the facebook api you can add to the details the "privacy" field:

```
    privacy = Array('value'=>'ALL_FRIENDS');
    $privacy =  (object)$privacy;
    $albumDetails = array(
            'name' => 'Album name',
            'privacy' => $privacy
    );
```

Possible values for 'value' are: `EVERYONE, ALL_FRIENDS, NETWORKS_FRIENDS, FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS, CUSTOM`. Please check the URL in the source (Below) for more information
Then make the API call normally. (Note that the privacy field might be overridden in some cases)

**Sources:**
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ (Scroll down to privacy)